# How to create a Odata service with Olingo and Spring Boot JPA 2023

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, odata, sapui5, olingo

I have to make a backend in spring boot that returns the information as an ODATA service, using olingo, jpa and spring boot.

But as of today there is no updated example on the internet.

It is all deprecated and nothing clear how to follow the updated examples.

Please, if someone could give me an example of how to do it, I would appreciate it.

technologies:
Spring Boot 3.0.5
JPA
Apache Olingo Odata v2
Java/Jakarta

these are the best examples I could find, but they are deprecated:

https://olingo.apache.org/doc/odata2/index.html

https://blogs.sap.com/2021/10/29/building-an-odata-service-with-a-spring-java-application-using-olingo-part-i/

Please, i need help.

I tried to update the examples in the tutorials but I could not, I am very lost, it is something new for me.

Comment: odata v2 is JavaEE and not JakartaEE so that simply won't work with Spring Boot 3.